# Duplicate dataframe row for each row that matches dict mapping

Tags: python, pandas

I was not sure how to word the title, so hopefully it's somewhat clear.

What I want is that with this dataframe and a mapping:

```
       isin        date  val
SE0000195570  2014-10-23  1
SE0000195570  2014-07-16  2
SE0000195570  2014-04-29  3
SE0000195570  2014-01-31  4          
SE0000191827  2018-10-19  5
SE0000191827  2018-07-11  6
SE0000191827  2018-04-20  7
SE0000191827  2018-02-16  8

mapping = {
  'SE0000195570': [1,2], 
  'SE0000191827': [4,5,6]
}
```

I want to produce this output.

```
       isin        date   sec   val
SE0000195570  2014-10-23    1    1
SE0000195570  2014-10-23    2    1
SE0000195570  2014-07-16    1    2
SE0000195570  2014-07-16    2    2
SE0000195570  2014-04-29    1    3
SE0000195570  2014-04-29    2    3
SE0000195570  2014-01-31    1    4
SE0000195570  2014-01-31    2    4

SE0000191827  2018-10-19    4    5
SE0000191827  2018-10-19    5    5
SE0000191827  2018-10-19    6    5
SE0000191827  2018-07-11    4    6
SE0000191827  2018-07-11    5    6
SE0000191827  2018-07-11    6    6
SE0000191827  2018-04-20    4    7
SE0000191827  2018-04-20    5    7
SE0000191827  2018-04-20    6    7
SE0000191827  2018-02-16    4    8
SE0000191827  2018-02-16    5    8
SE0000191827  2018-02-16    6    8
```

As you can see, each row for `SE0000195570` and `SE0000191827` has been repeated once for each element in their respective mappings. In a way, I've added a new column to the primary key and adjusted the frame size accordingly.

I tried simply adding the new column `sec` to the index but that didn't to anything useful. I'm kind of stuck on how to do this efficiently. Looping is probably not an option since my final table will be way past a million rows.

Comment: Sounds like a case for `merge`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Ben's answer with dict comprehension and house-keeping:

```
m_df = (pd.concat(pd.Series(v, index=[k]*len(v)) 
                           for k,v in mapping.items()
                ).to_frame(name='sec'))

# same merge
df.merge(m_df, left_on='isin', right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
           isin        date  val  sec
0  SE0000195570  2014-10-23    1    1
0  SE0000195570  2014-10-23    1    2
1  SE0000195570  2014-07-16    2    1
1  SE0000195570  2014-07-16    2    2
2  SE0000195570  2014-04-29    3    1
2  SE0000195570  2014-04-29    3    2
3  SE0000195570  2014-01-31    4    1
3  SE0000195570  2014-01-31    4    2
4  SE0000191827  2018-10-19    5    4
4  SE0000191827  2018-10-19    5    5
4  SE0000191827  2018-10-19    5    6
5  SE0000191827  2018-07-11    6    4
5  SE0000191827  2018-07-11    6    5
5  SE0000191827  2018-07-11    6    6
6  SE0000191827  2018-04-20    7    4
6  SE0000191827  2018-04-20    7    5
6  SE0000191827  2018-04-20    7    6
7  SE0000191827  2018-02-16    8    4
7  SE0000191827  2018-02-16    8    5
7  SE0000191827  2018-02-16    8    6
```

Answer (score 1):

Do with cross join after create the df

```
s=pd.DataFrame(list(mapping.values()), index=mapping.keys()).stack().reset_index(level=0)
df.merge(s,left_on='isin',right_on='level_0')
```

Comment: @ALollz Yep , and I am think of create the df from for loop , let me update :-)